# Solving a trig equation using subsitution

Tags: trigonometry

The equation is:

$\tan^4\theta+4\tan^3\theta-6\tan^2\theta-4tan\theta+1=0$

$\tan\frac{\pi}{16}$ is a root, as when $\frac{\pi}{16}$ is substituted in, the equation gives $0$.

By using the substitution $u=t-t^{-1}$

I can obtain the equation:

$u^{2}+4u-4=0$

Which gives $u=-2+2\sqrt2, u=-2-2\sqrt2$

I should be able to use the values of u to find an exact value for $\tan\frac{\pi}{16}$ but how do I do this?

Comment: Use your substituted equation and solve for t in terms of u. That gives you four solutions to the original equation. One of these solutions must be the root you found earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the solutions to $u$ should be $u=-2\pm\color{red}{2}\sqrt{2}$. Substituting these values into equation $u=t-t^{-1}$ and solving the quadratic in $t$ leads to
$$t=\frac{-(2\pm2\sqrt{2})\pm\sqrt{(2\pm2\sqrt{2})^2+4}}{2}$$
Hence there are $4$ possible solutions, out of which two are negative values (and so can be discarded  as $\tan\frac{\pi}{16}$ cannot be negative) and one value is greater than $1$ (which can also be discarded, as $\frac{\pi}{16}$ is less than $\frac{\pi}{4}$, and $\tan\frac{\pi}{4}=1$), leaving the following unique solution:-
$$\tan\frac{\pi}{16}=\frac{-(2+2\sqrt{2})+\sqrt{(2+2\sqrt{2})^2+4}}{2}=-1-\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}+4}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the Half-angle formulas $$\cos(x/2)=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(x)}{2}}$$ and $$\sin(x/2)=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(x)}{2}}. $$ This gives us a formula for $\tan(x/2)=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(x)}{1+\cos(x)}}.$ Put $x=\pi/4$ to get the value of $\sin(\pi/8),\cos(\pi/8)$ and $\tan(\pi/8).$ Then put $x=\pi/8$ to get the value of $\tan(\pi/16).$

Answer (score 0):

$tan(\pi/16) = -1 -\sqrt2 + \sqrt{4 +2\sqrt2}$
from http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tan+(pi%2F16)

now $u^{2}+4u-4=0$ has roots $u = -2 + 2\sqrt2 $ , $-2-2\sqrt2$

if $u = t - 1/t = -2-2\sqrt2$  then  $t=-1-\sqrt2 +\sqrt{4+2\sqrt2}$, so this proves $tan(\pi/16 )$ is a root of equation.